# How to delete the cell value in a given range if it contains a string value using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

Can anybody tell me how to delete the cells value in a given range if the cell value is String (Not a particular string, in general any String)
This is what I have tried so far:

```
  Dim UsedCell_Total, myRange
  UsedCell_Total = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row


   For Each cell In Range("A3:A" & UsedCell_Total)
   If (cell.value) = "*" Then  ' I dono't know what condition to give here

   cell.Delete shift:=xlRight
   End If
   Next cell
```

Comment: You should provide some VBA you have tried, see [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you haven't done anything yet look at using a `for` statement to loop through all cells in the range and then an `if` conditional to test against the cell contents using `TypeName` if this evaluates to being a string then delete the contents. Give it a go and if you have any issues then get back and update your question

Comment: If IsText(Cell.Value) = True or If IsString(Cell.Value) would be the condition. Do you really want to delete the cell or only the value? If you delete the cell be aware that the other cells get shifted, so if there would be a value in the shifted cell this will be given over to the new cell. Otherwise I would only delete the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way of achieving what you're looking for which will catch all cells that have Strings inside them. This uses the `TypeName` function to test the cells contents. If the Function evaluates to "String" it then deletes the cell

```
Dim UsedCell_Total as Long, cell

UsedCell_Total = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

For Each cell In Range("A3:A" & UsedCell_Total).Cells
    If TypeName(cell.value) = "String" Then cell.Delete shift:=xlRight
Next cell
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `IsNumeric()` with the `Not` operator to reverse the logic:

```
Dim UsedCell_Total As Long
Dim myRange        As Excel.Range
Dim cell           As Excel.Range

    UsedCell_Total = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row

    For Each cell In Range("A3:A" & UsedCell_Total).Cells
        If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
            cell.Delete shift:=xlRight
        End If
    Next
```

---

You might want to test for dates too *(dates aren't captured with `IsNumeric()`)* in which case you would use

```
If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) And Not IsDate(cell.Value) Then
```

Comment: Why not use `If TypeName(cell.Value) <> "String" Then` this would capture all

Comment: Just an alternative way - you should post an answer using the `TypeName` method.

Comment: It seems a bit redundant for just changing 1 line

Comment: Not really, it shows the OP another working example of how you can achieve the desired result. The other point is that someone in the future might come along and find this page with a slightly different requirement where one method might be more useful that the other. Your solution is more failsafe than mine for what the OP needs so you should post it.